# Prove: $A$ is $3\times4$ matrix of rank $3$, then there exists a $4\times3$ matrix $B$ such that $AB=I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

$A$ is $3\times4$ matrix of rank $3$, then how do we prove that there exists a $3\times4$ matrix $B$ such that $AB=I$

Clearly since the rank$(A)=3$, the reduced echelon form of $A (A')$ should have $3$ non-zero rows.

We obtain $A'$ by performing certain row operations
say  $r_{i}$

But we know that general form of $A'$ should be:
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & a\\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & b \\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & c\end{pmatrix}$$
where $a,b,c$ are real numbers

I am facing trouble with how to proceed further. How do we:
a) Use the fact that $A'$ is basically an identity matrix augmented with a real column matrix
b) Come up with a general method to obtain $B$

Comment: Please edit your post to include some thoughts: 1) How is $A$ related to its reduced echelon form $A'$? 2) Find a $B'$ such that $A'B'=I.$ 3) ...

Comment: The question must be in the body, not only (and even not necessarily) in the title.

Comment: You know that $A'$ has 3 nonzero rows, but you can't conclude $A'$ has the given form from that.

Comment: @BrianMoehring why not ? isn't A' the reduced row echelon form of A. I don't think that any other configuration would fit..

Comment: There are $\binom{4}{3} = 4$ possible choices for the pivot columns, so there are four different "general forms" of the flavor of the one you've written.  Otherwise you'd have to use column swaps as well to get it into the form you've written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the matrix A, we can do the row/column operations to make it into the standard form:

$$L_k...L_1AR_1...R_m=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & a\\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & b \\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & c\end{pmatrix}$$

Where $L_i, i=1,2...,k$ are elementary matrices for row operations, and $R_j, j=1,2...,m$ are elementary matrices of column operations. Let $T$ be the following matrix:

$$T=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\\ 0 & 1 & 0  \\\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

So we have:

$$\begin{align}
L_k...L_1AR_1...R_mT&=I\\
\\
AR_1...R_mT&=L_1^{-1}...L_k^{-1}I\\
\\
AR_1...R_mTL_k...L_1&=I\\
\\
\Rightarrow B&=R_1...R_mTL_k...L_1
\end{align}$$

Answer (score -1):

Since the $3 \times 4 $ matrix $A$ is of rank $3$, then the $3 \times 3$ matrix $A A^T$ is invertible, therefore, we can take $B$ to be

$ B = A^T (A A^T)^{-1} $